# Tapping nested GridView

Tags: android, gridview

There is a GridView (1G) (days in scheduler), each cell of which consists of another GridView (2G) (time segments).
The goal is: when you tap any cell of 2G the 1G cell in which 2G is nested must be activated.
What we have at the moment: the 2G cell activates.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try setting `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` on 1G.

Answer (score 0):

Normally children take precedence on their parents.

To prevent this take a look to [onInterceptTouchEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29).